# Where is the customer ID for Braintree payments stored in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment-gateway, braintree

I am trying to find the Customer ID that is used by the Braintree integration.

I have seen the two tables:

- vault_payment_token
- vault_payment_token_order_payment_link

Neither include any reference to the Customer ID with Braintree (as far as I can tell the Customer ID in Braintree differs to that of Magento).

I did think perhaps it doesn't store it but then that wouldn't make any sense as how would Magento manage to add new cards in to the vault for that customer on checking out.

Which table would I therefor (hopefully) find a reference to that?

Comment: Is this for Magento 1 or Magento 2?

Comment: @AshokDubariya Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as my testing shows, Magento 2 does not store the Braintree Customer ID.

If a customer adds multiple cards these are added to BT as multiple customers.

Why Mangento has setup the integration up like this I am not sure as it is a bit of an odd decision as far as I can tell from the outside.